# Start a Animation when I press a Button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a beginning Animation which is called divanimated. Its a rectangel which comes in. Now I want to start a 2nd Animation on this div when I hit a button. I don't know why it isn't working.
Here is my code:

```
    <div class="div"> </div>
    <img src="/arrowright.png" class="arrowright">
    <script> 
        $(".arrowright").click(function(){
            $(".div").toggleClass("divanimated");
        });
    </script>
```

css:

```
.divanimated{
animation-name: divanimated;
-webkit-animation-name: divanimated;    

animation-duration: 1.5s;   
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;    

transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;    

 background: #e74c3c;
z-index: 1;
width: 72.8vw;
height: 39vh;
margin-top: 136.5vh;   
margin-left: 13.6vw;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 7vh;
display: none;
box-shadow:2px 2px 10px #333333;
}

@keyframes divanimated{
0% {
    transform: scaleX(0.3);
}
40% {
    transform: scaleX(1.02);
}
60% {
    transform: scaleX(0.98);
}
80% {
    transform: scaleX(1.01);
}
100% {
    transform: scaleX(0.98);
}               
80% {
    transform: scaleX(1.01);
}
100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}                           
}

@-webkit-keyframes divanimated{
0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.3);
}
40% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.02);
}
60% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.98);
}
80% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.01);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.98);
}               
80% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.01);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
}       
}
.div{
animation-name: div;
-webkit-animation-name: div;    

animation-duration: 1.6s;   
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.6s;

animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease -out;

visibility: visible !important; 

background: #e74c3c;
z-index: 1;
width: 72.8vw;
height: 39vh;
margin-top: 136.5vh;   
margin-left: 13.6vw;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 7vh;
display: none;
box-shadow:2px 2px 10px #333333;
}

@keyframes div{
0% {
    transform: translateY(100%) scaleX(0.5);
}
30%{
    transform: translateY(-8%) scaleX(0.5);
}   
40%{
    transform: translateY(2%) scaleX(0.5);
}
50%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.1);
}
60%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.9);      
}
70% {
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.05);
}           
80%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.95);     
}
90% {
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.02);
}   
100%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1);        
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes div{
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) scaleX(0.5);
}
30%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8%) scaleX(0.5);
}   
40%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2%) scaleX(0.5);
}
50%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.1);
}
60%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.9);      
}
70% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.05);
}           
80%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.95);     
}
90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.02);
}   
100%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1);        
}
}
```

Can someone help me ? Whats wrong with my code ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information, your HTML, your JS for your first animation, more context, more code in order to have a functional example.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: Recreate it with CodePen: https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: @dennispreston OP shouldn't use codepen when they can include the code on SO. At a minimum, if they create a pen, they need to include the code in the post, too.

Comment: @Lixus
I edited my post. Sorry for this.

Comment: @MichaelCoker
I edited my post. Sorry for this.

Comment: @MichaelCoker true but a CodePen link was easier than explaining how to do that.

Comment: @dennispreston doesn't matter if it's easier. the point of SO is to be a reference for people with these problems now and in the future, and if OP links to their website, codepen, jsfiddle, etc, and either those links/code change or the sites are down or whatever, the question is worthless to people in the future if they can't refer to the original code. It's a requirement for posting. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: is this what you're going for? You need handle the `display: none` somehow, you're hiding the div and never unhiding it. But you need to add the `.divanimated` css after `.div` if you want that animation to work since `.div`'s css will overwrite the `animation` on `.divanimated` if `.div` comes before `.divanimated` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgGqLj

Comment: @dennispreston I recreated it with CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrwGzM

Comment: @MichaelCoker fair point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.div` and `.divanimated` selectors have the same specificity.  Because the `.div` style is specified **after** the `.divanimated` selector it will override all the similar attributes such as `animation-name`.

For this example, you could fix the problem by adding the `div` class to the `.divanimated` selector.

Your new CSS selector (line 1 of your CSS) would be:
`.div.divanimated`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer...

```js
// Created a JS function which we'll call when arrow is clicked
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("div").className = "divanimated";
}
```

```css
.arrowright{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  margin-left:90vw;
}

.divanimated{
  animation-name: divanimated;
  -webkit-animation-name: divanimated;    
  animation-duration: 1.5s;   
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;    
  background: #e74c3c;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 72.8vw;
  height: 39vh;
  margin-top: 136.5vh;   
  margin-left: 13.6vw;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 7vh;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 10px #333333;
}

@keyframes divanimated{
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0.3);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleX(1.02);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleX(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleX(1.01);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(0.98);
  }               
  80% {
    transform: scaleX(1.01);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }                           
}

@-webkit-keyframes divanimated{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.3);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.02);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.01);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.98);
  }               
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.01);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  }       
}

/* Moved this into a div ID as before it was moving the div down */
#div {
  visibility: visible !important; 
  background: #e74c3c;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 72.8vw;
  height: 39vh;
  margin-top: 40.5vh;   
  margin-left: 13.6vw;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 7vh;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 10px #333333;
}

.div{
  animation-name: div;
  -webkit-animation-name: div;    
  animation-duration: 1.6s;   
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.6s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease -out;
}

@keyframes div{
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%) scaleX(0.5);
  }
  30%{
    transform: translateY(-8%) scaleX(0.5);
  }   
  40%{
    transform: translateY(2%) scaleX(0.5);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.1);
  }
  60%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.9);      
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.05);
  }           
  80%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.95);     
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.02);
  }   
  100%{
    transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1);        
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes div{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) scaleX(0.5);
  }
  30%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8%) scaleX(0.5);
  }   
  40%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2%) scaleX(0.5);
  }
  50%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.1);
  }
  60%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.9);      
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.05);
  }           
  80%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(0.95);     
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1.02);
  }   
  100%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scaleX(1);        
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Added ID div and wrapped image with a div that listens for a click -->
<div id="div" class="div"> </div>
<div onclick="myFunction()">
  <img src="http://bbcpersian7.com/images/arrow-18.jpg" class="arrowright">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all which helped me :)
I got it and I am really happy about it. Thanks to all.